# PCA analysis considering N-less relevant components

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to learn the basics of PCA analysis in Python using scikit libraries (in particular sklearn.decomposition and sklearn.preprocessing). The goal is to import data from images into a matrix X (each row is a sample, each column is a feature), then standardize X, use PCA to extract principal components (2 most important, 6 most important....6 less important), project X on these principal components, reverse the previous transformation and plot the result in order to see the difference with respect to the original image/images.

Now let's say that I do not want to consider the 2,3,4... most important principal components but I want to consider the N less relevant components, let's say N=6.

How should the analysis be done?
I mean I can't simply standardize then call PCA().fit_transform and then revert back with inverse_transform() to plot the results.

At the moment I am doing something like this:

```
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) # standardize original data
pca = PCA()
model = pca.fit(X_std) # create model with all components
Xprime = model.components_[range(dim-6, dim, 1),:] # get last 6 PC
```

And then I stop because I know I should call transform() but I do not understand how to do it...I tried several times withouth being successfull.

Is there someone that can tell me if previous steps are correct and point out the direction to follow?

Thank you very much

---

EDIT: currently I have adapted this solution as suggested by the first answer to my question:

```
model = PCA().fit(X_std)
model2pc = model 
model2pc.components_[range(2, img_count, 1), :] = 0
Xp_2pc = model2pc.transform(X_std)
Xr_2pc = model2pc.inverse_transform(Xp_2pc)
```

And then I do the same for 6pc, 60pc, last 6 pc. What I have noticed is that this is very time consuming. I would like to get a model directly extracting the principal components I need (without zeroing out the others) and then perform transform() and inverse_transform() on that with that model.

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what you are trying to do... How are you going to use these principal components?

Comment: I have a set of 1087 rgb images divided into 4 categories, each image is 227x227 so the dimension of each image is 227x227x3. I open as a numpy array each image, reshape it (I use ravel() method) and add it to a matrix that has 1 row for each image and 1 column for each "feature" so in my case the matrix is 1087 x 154587. 
Let's call this matrix X. What I do is: standardize X, use PCA to extract 6 less important principal components and project X on these components. Then revert back the projection and plot one of the samples in order to see the difference with respect to the original image.

Comment: I can do this without any problem with the N-most important principal components because is just a matter of using the library function in the correct order but with the N-less important principal components is different.
What I am trying to do is to run PCA() on all components and then using the attribute components_ I can extract the last rows of the component's matrix. 
The problem is that after extracting the rows related to the N less important components I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore all but the last 6 principal components, you can just zero out the ones you don't want to keep.

```
N = 6
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
pca = PCA()
model = pca.fit(X_std) # create model with all components
model.components_[:-N] = 0
```

Then, to remove all but the last `N` components from the data, just do a forward and inverse transform of the data:

```
Xprime = model.inverse_transform(model.transform(X_std))
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> X = np.random.rand(18).reshape(6, 3)
>>> model = PCA().fit(X)
```

A round-trip transform should give back the original data:

```
>>> X
array([[0.16594796, 0.02366958, 0.8403745 ],
       [0.25219425, 0.22879029, 0.07950927],
       [0.69636084, 0.4410933 , 0.97431828],
       [0.50121079, 0.44835563, 0.95236146],
       [0.6793044 , 0.53847562, 0.27882302],
       [0.32886931, 0.0643043 , 0.10597973]])
>>> model.inverse_transform(model.transform(X))
array([[0.16594796, 0.02366958, 0.8403745 ],
       [0.25219425, 0.22879029, 0.07950927],
       [0.69636084, 0.4410933 , 0.97431828],
       [0.50121079, 0.44835563, 0.95236146],
       [0.6793044 , 0.53847562, 0.27882302],
       [0.32886931, 0.0643043 , 0.10597973]])
```

Now zero out the first principal component:

```
>>> model.components_
array([[ 0.22969899,  0.21209762,  0.94986998],
       [-0.67830467, -0.66500728,  0.31251894],
       [ 0.69795497, -0.71608653, -0.0088847 ]])
>>> model.components_[:-2] = 0
>>> model.components_
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.67830467, -0.66500728,  0.31251894],
       [ 0.69795497, -0.71608653, -0.0088847 ]])
```

The round-trip transform now gives a different result since we've removed the first principal component (which contains the greatest amount of variance):

```
>>> model.inverse_transform(model.transform(X))
array([[ 0.12742811, -0.01189858,  0.68108405],
       [ 0.36513945,  0.33308073,  0.54656949],
       [ 0.58029482,  0.33392119,  0.49435263],
       [ 0.39987803,  0.35478779,  0.53332196],
       [ 0.71114004,  0.56787176,  0.41047233],
       [ 0.44000711,  0.16692583,  0.56556581]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this approach works perfectly. 
My idea was different since the requirement I've got asks me to perform PCA for the first 2, 6, 60 and for the last 6 principal components. 
Basically I would like to perform PCA().fit(X) only once, then save the principal components I need in some variable and then use that variable to perform transform() and inverse_transform(). 
Is this feasible?

Comment: Sure. You could just  copy the `components_` attribute of the model to a temporary array. Then modify `components_` for each case you want to run. Alternately, you could just do the math yourself. If you look at the code for `PCA.transform` and `PCA.inverse_transform`, it is pretty simple.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I am already doing as added at the end of the first post. To be honest I am facing another issue now, after running inverse_transform() when I print the values of each image I see that they are all around exp(-16) which is really strange, in fact if I plot the image all I get is a black image. 
As far as I know inverse_transform() already takes care of de-standardizing the data...maybe the problem is that I standardize my entire dataset in the first place with StandardScaler().fit_transform()

Comment: If you want to compare to the original images, you should either skip the `StandardScalar` (probably best) or you need to apply its inverse transform after applying the PCA transform & inverse. If you want to reduce the amount of computation, you could compute the full set of PCs once, then for each set of PCs you want to use, make a copy of that array and zero out components (likewise for the eigenvector matrix). That would reduce the amount of computation but you would have to do the inverse part of the transform manually.